# $resource no funciona metodo POST angularjs

Tags: post, http

Tengo un problema con el $resource de AngularJS

No funciona el metodo $save, $delete ni $get, solo el query.

Las url ya estan creadas en el Backend y funcionan bien

```
/api/Descarga      GET      Trae todos
/api/Descarga      POST     Crea 1 registro nuevo
/api/Descarga/id   GET      Trae 1 registro
/api/Descarga/id   POST     Edita 1 registro
/api/Descarga/id   DELETE   Elimina registro
```

Todas las url fueron probadas con PostMan y Restlet Cliente y en todas las url se imprime un json con los datos correspondientes

El codigo de mi js es (angular-app.js):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"]);
app.controller('ProductoController', function($scope, $http, $resource) {
  var Descarga = $resource('/api/Descarga/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
      'get':    {method:'GET'},
      'save':   {method:'POST'},
      'update': {method:'POST'},
      'query':  {method:'GET'},
      'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
  });
  var descargas = Descarga.query();
});
```

Mi html es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ProductoController">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Productos</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="/ui/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/ui/js/angular-app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Aclaro que el backend esta en PHP y MySQL

Cuando hago un Descarga.get({id:39}); o un descargas[6].$save() ninguno de los 2 me devuelve algo

Cuando hago el .get() en consola me sale:

> "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Y cuando hagoel .$save() no me devuelve nada

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es que PHP no procesa datos enviados por Angularjs que es en json

Aca la solucion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data